# assign static IPs to vmware

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, static-ip

So I have 2-3 VM images that i will be working upon daily. And they get connected to three different IPs, and i am using MobaXterm to connect to these three different images using their IP addresses. As of now I hibernate the machine if I want to stop working so that the IP addresses don't changes. I have heard that we can assign static IP addresses for these images so that on a restart it will maintain that IP address and i won't need to look at what each one's IP address is again . How do I get about doing that?

Current situation
vmimage1, IP - 192.168.X.A
vmimage2, IP - 192.168.X.B
vmimage3, IP - 192.168.X.C

upon restart 
vmimage1, IP - 192.168.X.D
vmimage2, IP - 192.168.X.E
vmimage3, IP - 192.168.X.F

what i want upon restart
vmimage1, IP - 192.168.X.A
vmimage2, IP - 192.168.X.B
vmimage3, IP - 192.168.X.C

Thanks
PS: I am using VMware Player(Non-commercial use only)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the guest OSes, you can set a static IP on the guest operating system. That is how we have it set where I work. We use Windows and set the IP manually.

If you are still having issues, and can give us the OSes and other info, we can give you a better answer on how exactly to do that.

For CentOS, you need to edit the network config file as seen here: http://www.mustbegeek.com/configure-static-ip-address-in-centos/
In short, edit the file (usually) `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, change the `BOOTPROTO=` line to `BOOTPROTO=static`, and add the lines for IP address, gateway, and netmask.

For Fedora, you likely can just use `gnome-control-center network` and walk through the GUI.

Having not used either OS in a while, I don't have either to play with right now.

Comment: My vmimage1 and vmimage2 are on centos, vmimage3 is a fedora 20. And i am running them on my main OS is windows 8.1

Comment: sorry, very new to this. fedora, there is Wired option in the gui. Then in settings, there is identity which says its ipv4 address and that is what i want to be static. There is ipv4 option where its set as automatic(dhcp), should i change it to manual? <br>http://oi57.tinypic.com/6nzh51.jpg

Comment: Yes, change to manual, then put in the IP address you want it to have.